# Why can't I access the bin directory?

Tags: unix

Why can't I access the bin directory with the following command?

`ls /` this shows me the hidden bin folder

`cd bin` I get this error 'No such file or directory'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you do `cd bin` you look for a `bin` directory in the current working directory (which apparently doesn't exist).

To access the root bin directory, `/bin` you need to do

```
cd /bin
```

with the leading `/`.

Answer (score 3):

To further explain:

List the current directory's contents (either one):

```
ls .
ls
```

List the root directory's contents (wherever you are):

```
ls /
```

List the home directory's contents (wherever you are):

```
ls ~
```

So your first command listed the contents of a directory that was (likely) not the one you were in.  If you are wondering about your current directory, try

```
pwd
```

The prompt that you see does not always show the full path, since that would take up the entire screen.  You can modify this, but it's not desired.